# JavaScript Canvas save() and restore() between window resizes

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm wanting to use `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` on window resize. My entire source code is here in a snippet.

I restore the context settings on line 40 in the resize handler and I have the context resave on each frame redraw on line 71. With the current code, none of the settings are saved. The fill color is reset to black on a resize even though I explicitly save and restore those settings. Why isn't this working?

```js
//global variables
var currentSection = 0;
var parseScroll = function(event) {
  //find which <section> is in the viewport
  var sections = document.querySelectorAll("#container section");
  for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
    var position = sections[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom > 0){
      //percentage of the section that is in the viewport
      if(Math.round((sections[i].offsetHeight-Math.abs(position.top))/window.innerHeight*100) > 50){
        currentSection = i;
      }
    }
  }
}

//global classes
class canvasManager {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.c = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.resize();
    var timer = false;
    window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
      window.clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        this.resize();
      }.bind(this),100);
    }.bind(this));
    this.animation = 0;
    this.animate();
  }
  resize() {
    console.log('resize')
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.c.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.c.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.clearFrame();
    this.c.restore();
  }
  clearFrame(){
    this.c.clearRect(0,0,this.c.width,this.c.height);
  }
  initAnimationOne(){
    this.animationOne = {}
    //configure canvas and save settings for later reference...
    this.c.fillStyle = '#8AD1C6';
    this.c.shadowColor = '#8AD1C6';
    this.c.shadowBlur = 18;
    this.c.textBaseline = 'top';
    this.c.font = "800 50px monospace";
    this.canvas.style.background = '#333';
    this.animationOne.getRandomChar = function(){
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    }
  }
  animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(refresh.bind(this))
    function refresh() {
      switch(currentSection){
        case 0:
          this.clearFrame()
          if(typeof this.animationOne == 'undefined'){
            this.initAnimationOne();
          }
          this.c.restore();
          this.c.beginPath();
          this.c.fillRect(0,0,100,100)
          this.c.fillText(this.animationOne.getRandomChar().toString(),0,0)
          this.c.save();
          break;
        case 1:
          this.clearFrame();
          break;
        case 2:
          this.clearFrame();
          break;
        case 3:
          this.clearFrame();
          break;
        case 4:
          this.clearFrame();
          break;
        default:
          console.log('no selection')
      }
      //console.log(currentSection);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(refresh.bind(this));
    }
  }
}

//global events
window.addEventListener("load", init);

//use wheel when possible
//wheel works best for desktop browsers
//scroll works best for mobile browsers
//when wheel fires, cancel scroll listening
window.addEventListener('scroll',parseScroll);
window.addEventListener('wheel',function(event){
  window.removeEventListener('scroll',parseScroll);
  parseScroll(event);
});

//global functions
function init() {
  initCanvas();
}

function initCanvas() {
  var canvas = new canvasManager();
  var sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    sections[i].setAttribute("data-order", i);
  }
}
```

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

canvas{
  margin-bottom:-4px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:0;
  transition:background .5s;
  background:#fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:3px solid green;
}

section{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="container">
  <section>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
  <section>
    
  </section>
  <section>
    
  </section>
  <section>
    
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate post. That other post points out that the context is reset upon resize. I'm already aware of that. This post is about how to save and restore parameters between resizes taking the reset of the parameters into consideration.

Comment: That's a duplicate. " any associated contexts must be cleared back to their initial state". The context is just **not te same** anymore. For your case just save whatever props you need in variables and reapply them. But your code makes so little sense it's actually hard to give you a proper soluton, because yo should **never** rely on any particular state of your context at the beginning of a drawing frame. Make your drawing code have the control, always.

Comment: Does that override `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`? I'm still a little confused as to why those aren't working. I realize the ctx properties are reset which is why I'm saving and trying to restore over the reset. Are you suggesting that the reset nullifies the save and restore methods? Thanks.

Comment: Next thing I'll try is cloning the object and then restoring the object. Basically replicating save() and restore() manually.

Comment: Yes ot does **everyrhing** is ripped off. The pixel matrox has changed it makes no sense to keep anything from that previous state.